# Update model from database in entity framework is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If any changes have made on the datatype or constraints(e.g. not null - null) of a particular column in table and performing `Update model from database` (Refresh a particular table) in entity framework is not updating the entity model.

Each time I have to delete and re-create the table manually.

Is this only solution? or any other best way to do this?

Comment: are you using migrations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

delete the applicable table(s) from your `model`, than select `Update model from database`, EF usually only checks for new fields, not changes to existing fields.

Comment: This answer is probably correct for most cases of this error.

Comment: What if I add a new table in database?  Then your solution will not work!

Comment: @MahmoodJenami did you test this before you made this comment? can you say with 100% certainty that my solution will not work?

Comment: Yeah, That was exactly my case.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the new updated/created table in the database contains an identity key column (like an ID column). Entity Framework is especially sensitive when working with tables that don't represent uniqueness in their records.